# keys virtually "stuck" after remapping

Tags: command-line, xkb

/situation

I'm on this problem since several days, and to the point of considering switching back to Windows (which would make me sad, as i haven't used it since... 2010, iirc - but WoW Classic is coming, guys, i just can't pass that).

I'm not tech-savvy. I use something *buntu related since forever (currently Xubuntu), and it's usually good enough for me.

So, even if i'm a linux user since nearly a decade, please, eli5.

/configuration

I use a keyboard, a mice (currently Roccat Nyth), and a Tartarus Chroma v2 (a sort of mini keyboard for just one hand). And other input peripherals non related to my problem.

When i play WoW, it's with Tartarus+mice. I barely touch the keyboard.

The Tartarus, by default, is mapped as a regular keyboard, which is unsuitable for my needs.

It don't have any usable driver for linux (openrazer have an open issue for the Tartarus since years, so i don't expect it to work soon, if ever).

But it can be remapped with xkbcomp, as i learned on this page: https://lampjs.wordpress.com/2015/06/26/remapchange-your-secondaryusb-keyboard-keys/

There is my dump (without remapping) xkb file: https://pastebin.com/XpR9RDPd

There is my remapped file: https://pastebin.com/3pXSKiWX

It seem to work: checking with xev, i can confirm i have the remapped keys i want on the Tartarus, while the regular keyboard keys are unchanged.

/problem

When i use any key of the Tartarus with any modifier (shift, ctrl, alt), it switch back to it's unmapped state, and became "stuck" in that state until i press the physical key who is bind to that unmapped state (usually on my regular keyboard, but it also work with the Tartarus), to "unstuck" it (and it also make it switch back to it's mapped state).

If i unmap the Tartarus, i can't reproduce the problem, so i highly suspect my configuration file to be bad. But i have no idea what's wrong in it... I read the Arch Wiki page about xkbcomp, but barely understood it.

Help! ^^

Answer (score 1):

Can you try using `evtest` in terminal first? After that

```
sudo apt-get install evtest
```

and then select the USB device. This will get the raw USB input.
I like this idea and I want to remap the keyboard via MIDI signal and `patchbank/encryptions` to prevent keyloggers.

It may have something to do with the IRQ interrupt request for keyboard input.

Comment: How do i select the usb device ? The evtest man said a path in dev/input/ but there's a lot of things here.